# How can I fix this unparenthised code for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have no programming experience. I am updating a wordpress webpage and a plugin gave me a problem with a line of code:

Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in /srv/vhost/solartex.es/home/html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/editors/class-vc-frontend-editor.php on line 339

I have filezilla and access to the document that needs to be changed but I'm not sure where to put the parenthesis.

Here is the line of code

```
$host = isset( $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ? $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : isset( $s['HTTP_HOST'] ) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : $s['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Thanks in advance.

I just need to add a parenthesis afaik

Comment: "*I just need to add a parenthesis afaik*" - `$host = isset($s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']) ? $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : (isset( $s['HTTP_HOST'] ) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : $s['SERVER_NAME']);`

Answer (score -1):

Wow this is a mess. Here's the conditional expanded out of ternary operators:

```php
$host = $s['SERVER_NAME'];

if ( isset( $s['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) {
    $host = $s['HTTP_HOST'];
}

if ( isset( $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) {
    $host = $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```

Much easier to read and understand.

Comment: OP is using a plugin and shouldn't actually adjust said code but update the plugin

Comment: If there's an update available, sure. But if there's not, better to edit the plugin than site be unavailable due to fatal error.